# Get url path in Ajax request's onSuccess function

Tags: extjs

Following is my code for Ajax request:

```
 for(some loop) {
 var SOME-VARIABLE = value;
 new Ajax.Request(SERVER-PATH + SOME-VARIABLE, {
     asynchronous: true,
     method: 'get',
     onSuccess: function(response) {
     //here I require SOME-VARIABLE
     }
 }
```

So, I am performing multiple ajax request in loop, Request is working perfect. But I want value of variable(SOME-VARIABLE) portion of request url in respective callback. As multiple-request are performed, in callback I could not get the the actual value of variable(it is replaced by subsequent loop iteration) Is there any way that I could access request-url-path in response-object of `Onsuccess` function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curly brackets do not have scope in javasrcipt, but functions do. So wrap in-brackets code by function:

```
for(some loop) {
  var SOME-VARIABLE = value;
  (function(url) {
    new Ajax.Request(SERVER-PATH + url, {
      asynchronous: true,
      method: 'get',
      onSuccess: function(response) {
        //here You can access url
      }
    }
  }) (SOME-VARIABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store SOME-VARIABLE as a property in your request:

```
new Ajax.Request(SERVER-PATH + SOME-VARIABLE, {
    asynchronous: true,
    method: 'get',
    options: {SOME-VARIABLE: SOME-VARIABLE},
    onSuccess: function(response, obj) {
        alert(obj.options.SOME-VARIALBE);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Got this working using Extjs 3.1 and 4.0.2:

```
var myOption = 'asdf';
Ext.get('myButton').on('click', function(){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://jsfiddle.net/',
        options: {myOp: myOption },
        success: function(res, obj) {
            alert(obj.options.myOp);
        },
        failure: function(res, obj) {
            alert(obj.options.myOp);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Seemed simple solution, but doesn't worked, I found obj undefined.

Comment: What Ext version are you using?

Comment: yes, this is version problem, I am using Ext2.0.2, and I can not upgrade it, as this lib is part of another (third-party)framework. Thanks for correcting me.